# Smoothing before FPCA

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to use FPCA on my time series and I know that I should do some smoothing before using FPCA. However, I don't know what smoothing method is good?
Any resource is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Smoothing will depend on the data you have. Considering the FDA parametric approach (Ramsay & Silverman, 2005) the basis functions is your choice: in general, it is common to use the *“fourier”* basis for periodic data, and *“bspline”* basis for non-recurrent data. B-splines have a very good local behaviour.

You can find more info about the implementation of different basis functions in "Functional data analysis with R and MATLAB" (Ramsay et al. 2009)

There's no specific rule to choose the dimension of the basis as it depends on several factors. I strongly recommend studying the least square error of the process in all possible dimensions, and then to choose it by the region of convenience. Some packages have implemented functions to calculate it; e.g. `fda.usc::min.basis()` -*best* minimum number of basis functions-  and also by the cross-validation method, e.g. `fda.usc::CV.S()`.

P-splines provide the lowest approximation errors, its computational implementation is easier and are quite insensitive to the choice of knots. You can try to smooth your functional object like:

```
library(fda)   
fdobj <- create.bspline.basis(df,nbasis=k,norder=4)
smooth.fdPar(fdobj, Lfdobj=NULL, lambda=0,
             estimate=TRUE, penmat=NULL)
```